# IIS 6 content expiry and image cashing

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have new a favicon in production but this does not seems to be changing even after the IIS is restarted or using content expiry immediate.

Even after i do multiple refresh it is not seems to be loading.

Or is there any other way to refresh this data?

using meta keywords or HttpCacheability.NoCache can not be done as i belive these has to be added to the .net code or aspx and will not affect actual image cashing.

Could you please suggest?

Comment: This was happening due to the load balancer. After sometime it started appearing properly.